# I biled the bits of her

Tags: meaning

> 'Then why did you try to poison him?' Una asked wickedly, and Simon
>   hung his head like a shy child. 'Oh, that was when he set me to make a
>   pudden, for because our cook was hurted. I done my uttermost, but she
>   all fetched adrift like in the bag, an' the more **I biled the bits of
>   her**, the less she favoured any fashion o' pudden. Moon he chawed and
>   chammed his piece, and Frankie chawed and chammed his'n, and--no words
>   to it--he took me by the ear an' walked me out over the bow-end, an'
>   him an' Moon hove the pudden at me on the bowsprit gub by gub,
>   something cruel hard!' Simon rubbed his hairy cheek.

This is from "Simple Simon" by Kipling.
<sup>http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/simplesimon.html</sup>

I am glad if some one teach me the meaning of "I biled the bits of her"

Answer (score 2):

"Biled" means *boiled.* By spelling it differently, the writer is showing an unusual pronunciation of the word, common in some rural areas in the USA over a hundred years ago. So, something like this:

> He asked me to make a pudding, because our cook was hurt. I did my best, but it got all messed up in the bag, and the more I boiled the pieces of it, the less it looked like a pudding.

It was fairly common slang in the 1800's to refer to things as "she" rather than "it," in particular among sailors.

There's a verse from a song called "Springfield Mountain" that has something similar:

> One Friday morning he did go
>   Into the meadow and did mow
>   A round or two then he did feel
>   A pison sarpent at his heel.

A "pison sarpent" is a poison serpent.

Comment: Bobrodes, thank you so much for your kind anwer!! Hiroshi

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki You're very welcome.